# Compiling and bundling a local typescript package that's imported into my application with rollup

Tags: typescript, npm, rollup, monorepo

I have a monorepo and I'm trying to bundle an application that's importing a local typescript package.
I'm using rollup to bundle, but it's not compiling my imported typescript modules from the package.
I'm using @rollup/plugin-typescript v11.1.6 to compile.

**Error**

`[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)`

**rollup.config.js**

```
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
  cache: false,
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    nodeResolve(),
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
  ]
};
```

ts.config.json

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "test",
    "dist/**/*",
    "**/*spec.ts"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

ts.config.base.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2021",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */

    /* Emit */
    "composite": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    "emitDeclarationOnly": false,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "removeComments": true,

    /* Modules */
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",                      /* Specify what module code is generated. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    
    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    
    /* Compiler Diagnostics */
    "extendedDiagnostics": false,                        /* Discover where TypeScript is spending its time when compiling */
    "listEmittedFiles": true,                           /* Print names of generated files part of the compilation to the terminal. */
    "traceResolution": false                             /* Log resolution process for each processed file */
  },
  "paths": {
    "@myPackages/*": ["./packages/*"]
  }
```

I tried re-ordering the rollup plugins in the config file.
I tried to build/compile my packages and imports the output js files instead. This works, but I'd rather build/compile my local typescript packages in the bundling process and let my application refer to package ts files instead.

In a broader sense, do I have build my local typescript packages or can I just let rollup compile+bundle both my application and packages?